# Como selecionar 2 registros numa Tabela SQL numa determinada sequencia?

Tags: c#, sql

Tenho uma tabela com 100.000 registros e com os campos:

```
 id  |  dia  |  chuva_manha  |  chuva_tarde  |  chuva_noite
```

Gostaria de criar uma instrução que consulta-se a tabela e conta-se quantas vezes determinada sequencia de eventos acontece. Por exemplo quero pegar quantas vezes choveu num dia pela manhã e no outro dia choveu pela tarde.

Mas para isso tenho de criar 2 instruções `select` no C# e criar um laço `for` para validar o resultado (o gestor.EXE_READER é um CRUD que tenho implementado que faz toda a ligação e transação com o sql server, bastando apelas enviar a instrução SQL)

```
int valor = 0;
for(int id = 0; id <= 100000; id+)
{
    string query1 = "SELECT * FROM dbchuva WHERE [id] = id AND chuva_manha != 0";
    string query2 = "SELECT * FROM dbchuva WHERE [id] = (id + 1)  AND chuva_tarde != 0";
    DataTable dados1 = gestor.EXE_READER(query1);
    int Qtde1 = dados1.Rows.Count;
    DataTable dados2 = gestor.EXE_READER(query2;
    int Qtde2 = dados2.Rows.Count;
    if(Qtde1 !=0 && Qtde2 !=0)
    {
        int valor = 1;
    }
}
```

Ou

```
int valor = 0;
for(int id = 0; id <= 100000; id+)
{
    int id2 = id + 1;
    string query = "SELECT * FROM dbchuva";
    DataTable dados = gestor.EXE_READER(query)
    int val1= Convert.ToInt16(dados.Rows[id]["chuva_manha"]);
    int val2 = Convert.ToInt16(dados.Rows[id2]["chuva_tarde"]);

    if valor(val1 != 0 && val2 != 0)
    {
        valor = 1;
    }
}
```

Ambas as formas demandam muito consumo de tempo para processar devido a grande quantidade de valores da tabela que acaba travando todo o sistema.

Como poderia implementar de uma forma mais simples?
Como verificar que a linha X ocorreu o evento A e na linha X+1 ocorreu o evento B?
Ou melhor como contar quantas vezes ao acontecer o evento A, no registro subsequente ocorreu o evento B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que pude entender, quando chove, as colunas relacionadas a chuva recebem o valor `1`, quando não chove, recebem o valor `0`. Dependendo da sua versão do SQL Server, creio que você pode resolver tudo com uma única consulta:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) 
FROM   (SELECT c.chuva_manha, 
               Lead(c.chuva_tarde, 1, 0) 
                 OVER (ORDER BY c.dia) chuva_tarde_proximo_dia 
        FROM   dbchuva c) resumo 
WHERE  resumo.chuva_manha <> 0 AND resumo.chuva_tarde_proximo_dia <> 0;
```

A função analítica [LEAD](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) retorna um valor de uma coluna de acordo com um *offset* (deslocamento), caso não exista, retorna um valor padrão (são os parâmetros da função respectivamente). No caso acima, irá retornar o valor da coluna `chuva_tarde` do dia seguinte (1 de *offset*), obedecendo a ordem dos dias (`OVER (ORDER BY c.dia)`).

Após ter o resultado da função para todos os dias, é verificado se as duas condições são atendidas, retornando o número de vezes que os dois eventos ocorreram. Esse verificação tem que ser feita utilizando sub consulta pelo fato de não ser possível utilizar a função na clausula `WHERE`.

Você pode ajustar a consulta para quaisquer outras combinações de eventos.

Comment: Li sua resposta, e vi que se pode criar varios LEAD nessa mesma instrução, carammmba, resolveu a questao num piscar de olhos.

Comment: sim, muito útil a função, já me ajudou algumas vezes também, sem falar que não existe a necessidade de fazer a verificação direto pelo código, basta pegar o resultado

Comment: Consegue dar uma luz em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/386299/93308

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução ( apenas o sql)

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbchuva c1
WHERE [id] = id 
AND chuva_manha != 0"
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
            FROM dbchuva C2
            WHERE C2.id = (C1.id + 1)  
            AND C2.chuva_tarde != 0)
```

O [EXISTS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) procura a ocorrência de um registro na condição passsda,
no caso chuva a tarde no dia seguinte.

Comment: Ela unitariamente é muito eficiente, mas quando jogo-a num laço for no c# do Visual Studio, simplesmente ficou mais lento do que o processo anterior, na verdade no laço for, o tempo foi tão superior ao que achava demorado que cancelei o processo.

Comment: Esta construção em geral depende de um índice.