# Como concatenar uma instrução SQL Server?

Tags: sql

Tenho uma tabela no SQL Server Management Studio no qual tenho os campos
teste | 01 | 02 | 03 | 04 | 05 | 06 | 07 | 08
Cria um laço for no C# do Visual Studio em outra tabela que contava quantas vezes uma determinada nota Y saiu depois da nota X, sendo que este calculo demorava mais de 18 minutos, criei então toda uma instrução no SQL e o cálculo foi reduzido para 50 segundos. Tentei migrar o formato de instrução para esta tabela acima, mas como as colunas tem 2 casas decimais (01, 02, 03 .. 08) não consigo fazer a implementação da instrução sql para esta tabela em questão.
A instrução em questão seria:

```
DECLARE @nota1 INT
DECLARE @nota2 INT
DECLARE @posicao1 INT
DECLARE @posicao2 INT

SET @nota1 = 1
SET @nota2 = 2
SET @posicao1 = 1
SET @posicao2 = 2

WHILE @nota2 <= 20
BEGIN
    WHILE @nota1 <= 20
    BEGIN
        WHILE @posicao1 <= 7
        BEGIN
            WHILE @posicao2 <= 8
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO tabela2 ([nota1], [posicao1], [nota2], [posicao2], [qtde]) VALUES
                    (
                    @nota1,
                    @posicao1,
                    @nota2,
                    @posicao2,
                    (SELECT COUNT(1) AS 'Valor' 
                FROM tabela
                WHERE '[0' + @posicao1 + ']' = @nota1 AND '[' + @posicao2 + ']' = @nota2))
            SET @posicao2 += 1
            END
        SET @posicao1 += 1
        END
    SET @nota1 += 1
    END 
SET
 @nota2 += 1
END
```

A instrução SELECT para funcionar teria de ser igual a do exemplo:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS 'Valor' FROM tabela WHERE [01] = @nota1 AND [02] = @nota2
```

Como faço para a instrução while ao somar fique com duas casas decimais? Ou como concatenar?

Comment: Não entendi direito a pergunta, mas pra inserir duas casas decimais você pode usar `select campo + 0.00 as meuCampoFloat from tabela`

Comment: Criei a instrução While para percorrer as colunas de 01 a 08. Na instrução sql teria de ser por exemplo: SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE [01] = 5 mas a instrução while não colocará entre [ ] nem colocar com 2 casa, [01] e ao somar com o SET @posicao1 += 1 sai de 1 e vai para 2 e não [02]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apos muita pesquisa encontrei a funcao final

```
DECLARE @nota1 INT
DECLARE @nota2 INT
DECLARE @posicao1 INT
DECLARE @posicao2 INT

SET @nota2 = 2
WHILE @nota2 <= 20
BEGIN
    SET @nota1 = 1
    WHILE @nota1 <= 20
    BEGIN
        SET @posicao1 = 1
        WHILE @posicao1 <= 7
        BEGIN
            SET @posicao2 = 2
            WHILE @posicao2 <= 8
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO tabela2 ([nota1], [posicao1], [nota2], [posicao2], [qtde]) VALUES
                    (
                    @nota1,
                    @posicao1,
                    @nota2,
                    @posicao2,
                    (SELECT COUNT(1) AS 'Valor' 
                FROM tabela
                WHERE 
                    CASE
                        WHEN @posicao1 = 1 THEN [01]
                        WHEN @posicao1 = 2 THEN [02]
                        WHEN @posicao1 = 3 THEN [03]
                        WHEN @posicao1 = 4 THEN [04]
                        WHEN @posicao1 = 5 THEN [05]
                        WHEN @posicao1 = 6 THEN [06]
                        WHEN @posicao1 = 7 THEN [07]
                    END
                = @nota1 AND 
                    CASE
                        WHEN @posicao1 = 2 THEN [02]
                        WHEN @posicao1 = 3 THEN [03]
                        WHEN @posicao1 = 4 THEN [04]
                        WHEN @posicao1 = 5 THEN [05]
                        WHEN @posicao1 = 6 THEN [06]
                        WHEN @posicao1 = 7 THEN [07]
                        WHEN @posicao1 = 8 THEN [08]
                    END
                = @nota2))
            SET @posicao2 = @posicao2 + 1
            END
        SET @posicao1 = @posicao1 + 1
        END
    SET @nota1 = @nota1 + 1
    END 
SET
 @nota2 = @nota2 + 1
END
```